# Measure of a set??

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

I looking to find a measure of the following set:
$A=\{ (a_1,a_2,...a_k) \in \mathbb{R}^k : |1+a_1z_1+a_2z_2+...+a_kz_k|<\delta \}$
and where $z_i \in \mathbb{Z}$.
I believe the measure of this set should be $\mu(A) \le c\delta$  where $c$ is some constant.

Can any one suggest any thing? I also, would like to know what branch mathematics deals with a problems like this.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The measure of this set is infinite. As an illustration, take the two-dimensional case with $z_1=z_2=1$: the set is everything between the parallel lines $1+a_1+a_2=\delta$ and $1+a_1+a_2=-\delta$.

[image: strip]

It is true that the width of this strip is of order $\delta$, but that is a different thing.

Comment: Thank you very much. Super clear